# MIPS: Address out of range when fetching

Tags: overflow, mips

I am a beginner of MIPS. When doing insertion sort on MARS, I meet the same error of "address out of range" when fetching for both reclusive method and non-reclusive method.
Here are my codes for reclusive method:

```
    move $s0,$a1    # s0 = n
    jal isort_rec   

isort_rec:
    subu  $sp,  $sp,  16   #create its stack frame 
    sw    $ra,  8($sp)    #save the return address to caller
    sw    $s0,  4($sp)     #callee saved registers
    sw    $s1,  0($sp)     #callee saved registers
    
    ble $s0,$zero,out_rec   #out the reclusive when n <= 0
    
    subi $s0,$s0,1          #n=n-1
    jal isort_rec           #reclusive,saying that before it have been already sorted
    
    subi $t2,$s0,1      # i=n-1
    
    lw  $s1,str($s0)    # key = str[n]  $s1

while_loop:                 #while loop
    bltz $t2,out_loop       #out_loop consequence1
    lb $t1,0($t2)           # str[i]        $t1
    bge $s1,$t1,out_loop    #out_loop consequence2
    
    addi $t3,$t2,1      # $t3 = i+1
    lb $t4,0($t3)       # str[i+1]      $t4
    
    sb $t4,0($t1)       #str[i+1]=str[i]
    
    subi $t2,$t2,1
    j while_loop    #loop
    
out_loop:
    sb  $t4,0($s1)      # str[i+1] = key
    
#out_rec
out_rec:
    lw    $ra,  8($sp)    #restore the return address
    lw    $s0,  4($sp)    #restore $s0
    lw    $s1,  0($sp)    #restore $s1
    addi  $sp,  $sp,  16  #restore the stack pointer
    jr    $ra
```

error occur at line

```
out_loop:
    sb  $t4,0($s1)      # str[i+1] = key
```

and it is the address of $s1 out of range

thank you for reading such a long question, I will really appreciate if any of you could help me debugging
thanks a lot!!

Comment: Ok, what's in $s1 when the error happens?

Comment: it‘s the last element of the input

Comment: So why are you trying to use that value as an address? The address of a value and the value itself are two different things.

Comment: That `lw  $s1,str($s0)` also looks weird. Why are you loading a word (4 bytes) if you're going to compare it against single bytes in the loop? And how do you ensure that `str($s0)` stays word-aligned since you seem to be decrementing `$s0` in one-byte steps? Also, keep in mind that `lb` sign-extends the value it loads.

Comment: Thanks，I'll try to correct it'